# c++ Build Error - undefined reference to base class constructor

Tags: c++, oop

Using a base class called Collection, I need to implement my derived class, VariableArray. However, I keep getting the error message

**undefined reference to `Collection::Collection()'**

I am not certain what  I need to do here. I have a constructor defined(none virtual in my base class), along with a copy constructor, and a virtual destructor.  In the derived class definition file, I included the code below, but I still get the error message.

```
VariableArray::VariableArray():Collection()
  {         }
```

Please any help will be appreciated.

## BASE CLASS

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Collection
{
    public:
                Collection();
                Collection( const Collection & );
            virtual ~Collection()=0;
            virtual bool add(const int x) =0;
            virtual int& remove() = 0; 
            virtual Collection& operator=(const Collection& rhs)=0;
            virtual int& operator[](int index) =0;   
        virtual const int& operator[](int index)const =0; 
        Collection& copy(); 
                int size_();

    protected:

    private:
               int _size;  

};
```

Comment: Do you have a no argument constructor defined for your Base class `Collection`? Show us the definition of Base class. The statement you have shown is *calls* the Base class constructor in the initialization list.

Comment: I have updated the post with info on the base class

Comment: Have you defined `Collection()`? [This](http://ideone.com/8pbHa) is  my best guess about your problem at the moment.

Comment: To put it plainly, your `Collection()` constructor needs a body. If it has one, the linker isn't finding it.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to have been the problem. I would not have guessed that at all.

Comment: Could Alok or Chris please add their comment as an answer and Kobojunkie accept it?

Comment: You probably miss the definition Collection::Collection { }; in your collection.cpp file?